# Getting "There is already an object named 'Mytable' in the database" error

Tags: sql-server-2012

I keep getting the following message:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Procedure tr_AuditTableChange, Line 9
>   There is already an object named 'Mytable' in the database.

Not sure what I am doing wrong and I can't figure out what this is.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Sounds like you have a DDL trigger in your database that is trying to create an object called `Mytable`.

Comment: Post the code from the stored procedure to illustrate what is being done.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the source code for trigger tr_AuditTableChange.

If it's creating a permanent table, see if it can use a #temp table instead, or better yet simple normal variables.

If it must use a permanent table, then quit creating and/or dropping that table, and leave it in place permanently.  If you have multiple sessions possibly stepping on each other, add @@SPID, but this is a bad technique in the first place.

For an auditing trigger, the auditing should do at most the following things

- Insert into your audit table (which should have INSERT only permissions for normal users - no SELECT, no UPDATE, no DELETE).
- ROLLBACK unauthorized transactions (if absolutely required)
- Notify administrators of unauthorized transactions (if absolutely required).